# Why is my data printing incorrectly? Payment Calculator Table

Tags: java

I cannot seem to figure out why the data is coming out wrong. I think my equations are coded correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
package loanmonthlycalc;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoanMonthlyCalc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    //Get Data
    System.out.println("Loan Monthly Payment Table");
    System.out.print("Enter loan amount: \n");
    double loanAmount = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter rate range: \n");
    double initialRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double finalRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter rate count: \n");
    int rateCount = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Print Table
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Year |");
    double rate = initialRate;
    double inc = ((finalRate - initialRate) / (rateCount - 1));
    for (int count = 1; count <= rateCount; count++) {
        String percent = "%";
        System.out.printf("%8.2f%s ", rate * 100, percent);
        rate = (rate + inc);
    }//for each rate
    System.out.print("\n-----|");
    for (int count = 1; count <= rateCount; count++) {
        System.out.print("-----------");
    }
    int constantA = 50000;
    System.out.println();
    if (loanAmount <= constantA) {
        for (int year = 1; year <= 10; year++) {

            System.out.printf("%4d |", year);

            for (int count = 1; count <= rateCount; count++) {
                int monthCount = (year * 12);
                double monthlyRate = (rate / 12);
                double rateFactor = (Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, monthCount));
                double monthPay = loanAmount * monthlyRate * rateFactor / (rateFactor - 
                System.out.printf("%10.2f", monthPay);
            }//for

            System.out.println();
        }//for

    }//if


    if (loanAmount > constantA) {
        for (int year = 5; year <= 30; year += 5) {

            System.out.printf("%4d |", year);

            for (int count = 1; count <= rateCount; count++) {
                int monthCount = (year * 12);
                double monthlyRate = (rate / 12);
                double rateFactor = (Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, monthCount));
                double monthPay = loanAmount * monthlyRate * rateFactor / (rateFactor - 
                System.out.printf("%10.2f", monthPay);
            }//for
            System.out.println();
        }//for

    }//if


}//Main
}//LoanMonthlyCalc


and here is my output:

Loan Monthly Payment Table
Enter loan amount: 
140000
Enter rate range: 
.04 .1
Enter rate count: 
5


Year |    4.00%     5.50%     7.00%     8.50%    10.00% 
-----|-------------------------------------------------------
   5 |   3078.97   3078.97   3078.97   3078.97   3078.97
  10 |   1968.34   1968.34   1968.34   1968.34   1968.34
  15 |   1635.47   1635.47   1635.47   1635.47   1635.47
  20 |   1493.00   1493.00   1493.00   1493.00   1493.00
  25 |   1423.06   1423.06   1423.06   1423.06   1423.06
  30 |   1386.41   1386.41   1386.41   1386.41   1386.41
```

The table should look like this:

```
Year |     4.00%     5.50%     7.00%     8.50%    10.00%
-----|------------------------------------------------------------
   5 |   2578.31   2674.16   2772.17   2872.31   2974.59
  10 |   1417.43   1519.37   1625.52   1735.80   1850.11
  15 |   1035.56   1143.92   1258.36   1378.64   1504.45
  20 |    848.37    963.04   1085.42   1214.95   1351.03
  25 |    738.97    859.72    989.49   1127.32   1272.18
  30 |    668.38    794.90    931.42   1076.48   1228.60
```

The 2 equations given for this assignment are:

Monthly Payment = Loan Amount * Monthly Rate * Rate Factor / (Rate Factor-1)

where, Rate Factor = (1+monthly rate)^(month count)

I have assumed that:

monthly rate = rate/12

and

month count = (year * 12)

Answer (score 1):

Note the missing `%`

Change

```
 System.out.printf("10.2f", monthPay);
```

to

```
  System.out.printf("%10.2f", monthPay);
```

Move the if out of the for like this:

```
  if (loanAmount <= constantA) {
        for (int year = 1; year <= 10; year++) {

            System.out.printf("%4d |", year);

            for (int count = 1; count <= rateCount; count++) {
                int monthCount = (year * 12);
                double monthlyRate = (rate / 12);
                double rateFactor = (Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, monthCount));
                double monthPay = loanAmount * monthlyRate * rateFactor / (rateFactor - 1);
                System.out.printf("%10.2f", monthPay);
            }//for

            System.out.println();
        }//for

    }//if
```

Comment: That fixes part of it, but It still isn't lining up correctly!

Comment: Why is `constantA` `50000`?

Comment: B/c that is part of the assignment. If the loan amount is less than or equal to 50000 then the years go from 1-10 in 1 year increments. If the loan amount is greater than 50000 then the years go from 5 to 30 in 5 year increments.

Comment: but in the first for loop the `"%4d |` is not printed, because `loanAmount` is bigger thatn  `constantA`

Comment: Shouldn't it just move on to the second loop then?

Comment: Yes. If only one loop is supposed to  be executed each time, have the  loops inside the `if`s, so that only one is executed each time

Comment: I did that, and it did help, but the numbers are still wrong, and there's a huge gap in between the first row and the last 6.

Comment: Could you [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15302753/edit) and add the new code after the changes, and the output it produces? Also add a comment here when you do it so I get notified

Comment: @user2149738 See edit. The if should be out of the for (in both loops that is).

Comment: Alright. I edited it. The only issue now seems to be the numbers themselves.

Comment: Add the equations to post, (or post a link), so that we can check if they are coded correctly

Comment: @user2149738 hmmm. Not sure why you get different results. The equations are coded correctly... Keep bumbing the question by editing iit and maybe someone else will give it a shot.